# How is the colon operator defined in the context of image magick command line usage

Tags: imagemagick

I can't find any documentation for this.

I have found examples in the [image magick documentation](https://imagemagick.org/script/command-line-processing.php) which use a colon but nothing explicit about how the colon is interpreted.

The examples are confusing ;

```
magick -size 640x480 pattern:checkerboard checkerboard.png
```

suggests it sets the attribute on the left (pattern) to the value on the right (checkerboard)

but then

```
magick -size 640x480 -depth 8 rgb:image image.png
```

suggests it sets file type of image - the thing on the right - to what is left of it

**EDIT**

This was all just a brain fart on my part; I was thinking (for various reasons) of "image" as a thing being made/assigned rgb which makes no sense (as "image" is a file name / input parameter).

The sensible interpretation is obviously of rgb as a thing (image of type rgb) being assigned the info in the file "image" .

So from these two examples at least, it appears the colon just assigns/applies the right hand operand to the left hand operand as you would expect.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are a couple of ways the colon is used.

Some options which create their own canvas have a colon, for example:

- `xc:` creates a canvas
- `gradient:colourA-colourB` creates a gradient from colourA to colourB
- `tile:` creates a repeated tile
- `radial-gradient:` creates a radial gradient
- `rose:` creates the built-in rose image
- `pattern:` for a built-in pattern as you saw
- `logo:` for the ImageMagick logo
- `label:` for text labels
- `caption:` for text captions

Then the colon sometimes prefixes a filename to tell ImageMagick what is in it. This is your `rgb:` use case, and it is necessary because the filename doesn't happen to end in `.rgb`. Other examples of this are:

- `gray:` when the greyscale input file doesn't end in `.gray`
- `tif:fd:5` read a TIFF from file descriptor 5

Or to tell it to write a specific variant of a file, e.g.:

- `PNG8:` to write a palettised PNG
- `PNG24:` to write an RGB888 PNG
- `PNG32:` to write an RGBA8888 PNG with alpha
- `PTIF:` to write a pyramid TIFF
- `BMP3:` to write a version 3 Microsoft BMP file
- `fd:3` write output on file descriptor 3
- `gif:fd:4` write output as GIF on file descriptor 4

There is some documentation [here](https://imagemagick.org/script/command-line-processing.php).

Comment: Cheers! (upvoted earlier when meant to accept so win win there)

Comment: See also: https://imagemagick.org/script/formats.php#builtin-images and https://imagemagick.org/script/formats.php#pseudo and https://imagemagick.org/script/formats.php#builtin-patterns. They all use the colon following the name

Comment: @Mark The documentation you linked to is where I started out. Initially I read your answer as "how a colon is interpreted depends entirely on the context in which it is used and is somewhat arbitrary" ... but I think I may just have been reading things incorrectly and there may be an "assign right to left" consistency here (?); eg. if I read the rgb: example as assigning a file "image" to an rgb object.

Comment: `@Bob`. What is your questions now?

Comment: @fmw42 I was wondering if it is correct to say that the thing on right (of the colon) is always used as input to the thing on left (of the colion) and never the other way around.
I suspect this is the case.
Only a developer could say for definite if this is the case, though a very experienced user might know if it is not ( by an example case ).

Comment: `@Bob`. I do not think it is that simple. If the colon is on the left of an actual image file, it can be prefaced with the file format. For example -- PNG:imagename.png or PNG:imagename (without the suffix) forces the image to be read or written as PNG. But you have some Imagemagick internal images or pseudo images or patterns that are just a name followed immediately with a colon with no space. For example -- logo: or canvas: